# ASP.Net Core 1.0 RC2 : What are LAUNCHER_PATH and LAUNCHER_ARGS mentioned in web.config?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

There are [breaking changes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vc4nBxcVe7I&list=PL0M0zPgJ3HSftTAAHttA3JQU4vOjXFquF&index=2) in ASP.NET 5 RC2 release:

- It is rebranded to ASP.NET Core 1.0 ([ASP.NET 5 is dead](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET5IsDeadIntroducingASPNETCore10AndNETCore10.aspx))
- Good bye `dnvm` and `dnu` command line, they are replaced by `dotnet`
- Various necessary code changes

I am trying to deploy the files generated by `dotnet publish`. The files structure is different from RC1. I see the following error in the Event Viewer:

`Failed to start process with commandline '%LAUNCHER_PATH% %LAUNCHER_ARGS%', Error Code = '0x80070002'.`

These environment variables are mentioned in `web.config`, which is taken from the [official rc1-to-rc2](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/migration/rc1-to-rc2.html) document.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*"
              modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%"
        stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"
        forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

What are the correct values for `%LAUNCHER_PATH%` and `%LAUNCHER_ARGS%` ? These values are not mentioned in their [github publish document](https://github.com/GuardRex/Docs/blob/master/aspnet/publishing/iis.rst).

Answer (score 56, accepted):

From github [IISSample](https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/blob/dev/samples/IISSample/web.config) (thank you @Pawel and Luke), here are the value possibilities:

```
<!-- This set of attributes are used for launching the sample using IISExpress via Visual Studio tooling -->
<aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>

<!-- This set of attributes are used for launching the sample for full CLR (net451) without Visual Studio tooling -->
<aspNetCore processPath=".\IISSample.exe" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>

<!-- This set of attributes are used for launching the sample for Core CLR (netcoreapp1.0) without Visual Studio tooling -->
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\IISSample.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
```

After several hours dealing with them, I found there are **two** web.configs that we need to deal with: `src\ProjectName\wwwroot\web.config` and `src\ProjectName\web.config` . If you dont have the latter, VS2015 publish will generate one for you with `%LAUNCHER_PATH%` and `%LAUNCHER_ARGS%` by default.

To have the project run and debuggable locally under VS2015 via IISExpress, both web.config need to have the default value below. Replacing LAUNCHER_PATH and LAUNCHER_ARGS to something else causes VS2015 to hang indefinitely.

```
<aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
```

However, upon deploying to IIS (I am using 8.5 on WinServer 2012 R2), the value on `src\ProjectName\web.config` must be replaced with the following. If configured, the `dotnet publish-iis` command suppose to do the replacement for you (see below).

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\ProjectName.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
```

If you are migrating from RC1, [change](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/173) the http bound directory as well to Project root folder, not wwwroot. Example: from `C:\inetpub\ProjectName\wwwroot` to `C:\inetpub\ProjectName`.

To [configure](https://github.com/aspnet/cli-samples/blob/master/HelloMvcApi/project.json#L21-L29) `publish-iis` to do automatic replacement, add this snippet to your project.json: (Thank you @Pawel)

```
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%"
  }
```

The IISIntegration tool segment converts these Launcher variables to the appropriate deployment values. Without it, you will get the following error:

```
No executable found matching command "dotnet-publish-iis"
```

I am using RC2 Toolkit Preview 1.

Comment: I don't think we need 2 web.config for RC2. I believe the one in wwwroot is useless now.

Comment: @maxisam not really. the `project\wwwroot\web.config` is used to generate `project\web.config` . If you configure your `project.json` as above, it will use your `project\wwwroot\web.config` as a template.

Comment: Ah... you can try it yourself. It works correctly without having web.config in wwwroot. And yes, I use the same scripts in project.json. In fact, it is how new template does when you upgrade to `1.0.0-preview1-002702`

Comment: +1 for this `"postpublish": "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%"`. I was migrating from RC2 to 1.0 final and IIS deploy was not changing the web.config

Answer (score 10):

The `%LAUNCHER_PATH%` and `%LAUNCHER_ARGS%` are used by VS. publish-iis tool (if configured) will override them when you publish your application.

Comment: Where do I find publish-iis tool? Is it possible for me to call it via command line somewhere?

Comment: The tool is brought to you by specifying a reference in the `tools` section in your poject.json and `dotnet restore`ing your project. Wile you can run the tool from command line the typical usage is to configure it as a post publish script. See my post for more details: https://blog.3d-logic.com/2016/06/08/running-asp-net-core-applications-with-iis-and-antares/

Answer (score 10):

This is part of web.config in VS:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%"
    stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"
    forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
```

And this is on the server after publishing:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\AppName.dll" 
    stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" 
    forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
```

In this example `%LAUNCHER_PATH%` was replaced by `dotnet`, and `%LAUNCHER_ARGS%` by `application name` with `.dll` extension

Comment: why forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"  ? Seems necessary to run on IIS Express with processPath="dotnet"

Comment: So if the app is running under local IIS, then how do these values get corrected?  There is no "publish" when running the application directly from IIS.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help guys, I was using a template (https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-angular2-universal) and the command

```
dotnet publish
```

made a folder under

```
bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/publish
```

Setting this path as the root directory of the site made it work!