# Why running iisexpress.exe from command prompt with /path: set to Web Project's source folder fails?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net core Web Project created with Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.
When I do "Debug\Start Without Debugging..." from Visual Studio IDE, everything works correctly.
But, if I go to the command prompt and execute

```
 iisexpress.exe /path:full-path-to-the-folder-with-my-asp-project /port:some-port-number
```

then, even thought the iisexpress does start, any attempt to load project's url results in

```
  HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure
```

error.
Logs do not help with finding out the reason.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37463186/asp-net-core-1-0-rc2-what-are-launcher-path-and-launcher-args-mentioned-in-web.    web.config file that's located at the same level as wwwroot folder  is slightly different for launching from Visual Studio IDE and from command-line IISExpress